# In Visual Studio native unit test, is it possible to couple unit test to a project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, project

I have a solution, with three projects

```
Solution
-Project 1
-Project 2
-Project 3
```

Recently wanted to implement a unit test (or integration test) to make sure everything still works, and I have experience with CppUTest, but wanted to see if anything VS has to offer might be "better" integrated for this purpose.

So I followed a guide and it led me to another project.

-Unit test project (aka project 4), which is only a class from the looks of it.

```
Solution
-Project 1
-Project 2
-Project 3
-Project 4 (Unit test, testing Project 1)
```

So I'm wondering what's a good practice to maintain unit/integration testing environment?

It could be...

One unit test project, multiple unit tests classes, one for each project

```
Solution
-Project 1
-Project 2
-Project 3
-Project 4 (Unit test, testing Project 1, 2 and 3)
```

A Unit test project per working project
One unit test project, multiple unit tests classes, one for each project

```
Solution
-Project 1
-Project 2
-Project 3
-Project 4 (Unit test, testing Project 1)
-Project 5 (Unit test, testing Project 2)
-Project 6 (Unit test, testing Project 3)
```

Just apply unit test class to existing projects (not sure if it's possible)

```
Solution
-Project 1
 -Code
 -Unit Test
-Project 2
 -Code
 -Unit Test
-Project 3
 -Code
 -Unit Test
```

Is the third option possible?

Comment: I'd say it's a matter of opinion and thus the question is off-topic as "primarily opinion based".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to the accepted answer, I'd say to definitely put your test code into a separate project. Whether you create a single or multiple test projects is a matter of opinion, but there are good reasons to not put your test code into your release code.

The main reason is that you don't want to **link unit test libraries into release code**. That's simply unacceptable in my book and as far as I know Visual Studio has a clear "1 project = 1 library" approach so I don't see how you'd avoid that.

Using one unit test library per project means you can develop projects independent of others and you can easily specific which tests you want to run instead of having to run the tests for the whole solution. You could even set up continuous testing to get feedback much quicker about the code while you're writing (actually not sure if anybody has that working for C++, it's quite common for managed languages at least).

Also if you're using Microsoft's unit test framework you can just use the template [they provide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598953.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which also forces you to create a separate project for your tests.